# How to update form using [proifle.js] file Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on Reactjs and using Nextjs Framework,Right now i am working on admin
panel and trying to update user profile,For this i created file "[profile.js]" and pass userId
And i trying to fetch User information inside form,and want to update form means whenever
user click on "update" then information should updated via Axios(Api already created), But how can i use "form submit" ? in other words how can i get value of form/use function in nextjs ?
Here is my current code

```
const Post = ({ post }) => {
    // want to get form data and .....further code
}

return (
    <>
         <form className="forms-sample" >
             <input
                 type="text"
                 className="form-control"
                 id="exampleInputName1"
                 placeholder="Title"
                 name="name"
                 value={Post.title}/> //not showing
             <button type="submit" className='btn btn-primary mr-2'>Submit</button>     
         </form>
    </>
);
    
export const getStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/getblogbyuserid/${params.slug}`);
    const post = data;
    return {
        props: {
            post,
        },
    };
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
    const { data } = await Axios.get("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/api/blogs");
    const posts = data.slice(0, 10);
    const paths = posts.map((post) => ({ params: { slug: post.id.toString() } }));
    return {
        paths,
        fallback: true,
    };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
const submitHandler = (formData) => {
   // your code
}

<form className="forms-sample" onSubmit={submitHandler}>
```

Comment: its not working giving me error, Are you usre "submithander" will work just above form tag ?

Comment: not just above. Use it before returning your jsx element

Comment: i tried but not worked, can you write full code